# How to make table visual show all rows (rather than distinct)?

Tags: powerbi

**Sales:**
saleid, saledate, amt, customername

When I place all the above into a table visual then it shows 1 record per sale row.

However, when I only place the customername into a table visual, then it shows me distinct customernames. It looks like the table visual is actually a pivot table and not a normal table.

How do I make it to display 1 record per sale like a normal table even when customername is the only column in the visual?

Comment: You can't and this behavior is by design.